# Cypress: extract value from JSON body to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I am using cypress.io to test an API(Created using Node.js). I want to extract value from JSON response of the API and save it to a variable.

I have tried solutions mentioned in the below links it did not work:
[Cypress - get value from json response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031254/cypress-get-value-from-json-response-body)

Below is the code i am using to test the API:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
describe("Testing Provider Catalog API", () => {
    it("Provider Catalog API GET Request", () => {
        cy.request('GET', 'v1/providers')
            .then((response) => {
                expect(response).to.have.property('status', 200)
                expect(response.body).to.not.be.null
                // expect(response.body.providers).to.have.length(1)
            })
        cy.screenshot()
    })
    it("Provider Catalog API POST Request", () => {
        const provider = {
            "type": "loadboard",
            "name": "123loadboard"
        };
        cy.request('POST', 'v1/providers', provider)
        cy.screenshot()
    })
    it("Provider Catalog API PUT Request", () => {
        const provider = {
            "type": "loadboard",
            "name": "123loadboard"
        };
        cy.request('PUT', 'v1/providers/61a54a66a2b734859481931c', provider)
        cy.screenshot()
    })
    it("Provider Catalog API DELETE Request", () => {
        cy.request('DELETE', 'v1/providers/61a68e7ca6011e605029191b')
        cy.screenshot()
    })
})
```

Below is the code that i am using

```
       var providerId
        cy.wait('@newObject').then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
            expect(response.responseBody).to.have.property('_id')
            const body = (response.responseBody)
            providerId = body['_id']
        })
        cy.get(someInput).type(newId)
```

Sample output of the API:

```
{
"_id":"61a54ba1a2b7348594819323",
"type":"loadboard",
"name":"123loadboard",
"__v":0
}
```

I want to store the value of the _id in a variable and use it later.  I have been trying to for the last couple of days and nothing seems to work.  Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to use variables with cypress is with aliases. See docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases).

In your code, you can `wrap()` your `_id` and save it as an alias, then call your alias somewhere else in your code:

```js
cy.wait('@newObject').then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    expect(response.responseBody).to.have.property('_id')
    cy.wrap(response.responseBody._id).as('newId')
})
// then later in your code use:
cy.get('@newId').then((newId) => {
    cy.get(someInput).type(newId)
})
```

You could also `type()` your `_id` inside your `wait()`:

```js
cy.wait('@newObject').then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    expect(response.responseBody).to.have.property('_id')
    cy.get(someInput).type(response.responseBody._id)
})
```

Or you can use cypress global environmment object `Cypress.env()`. See docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env).

```js
cy.wait('@newObject').then((response) => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    expect(response.responseBody).to.have.property('_id')
    Cypress.env('newId', response.responseBody._id)
})
// then later in your code use:
cy.get(someInput).type(Cypress.env('newId'))
```